# Bind a click event to a method inside a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, binding, click

In the constructor of my object, I create some span tag and I need to refers them to a method of the same object.

Here is an example of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = new myObject("name");
});

function myObject(data){
    this.name = data;

    //Add a span tag, and the onclick must refer to the object's method
    $("body").append("<span>Test</span>");
    $("span").click(function(){
        myMethod(); //I want to exec the method of the current object
    }); 


    this.myMethod = myMethod;
    function myMethod(){
        alert(this.name); //This show undefined
    }

}
```

With this code the method is called, but it is not a reference to the object (this.name show undefined)
How can I resolve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: its because `this` would be referring to the current scope(which would be the event which triggered it i.e., click)

Answer (score 6):

One simple way to achieve that:

```
function myObject(data){
    this.name = data;

    // Store a reference to your object
    var that = this;

    $("body").append("<span>Test</span>");
    $("span").click(function(){
        that.myMethod(); // Execute in the context of your object
    }); 

    this.myMethod = function(){
        alert(this.name); 
    }
}
```

Another way, using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
function myObject(data){
    this.name = data;

    $("body").append("<span>Test</span>");
    $("span").click($.proxy(this.myMethod, this)); 

    this.myMethod = function(){
        alert(this.name); 
    }
}
```

Comment: or we could just use `data` instead of `this.name `

Comment: @GokulKav Or $.proxy, as I just added. Or bind. There are multiple solutions

Comment: @GokulKav Thanks. Why don't you add an answer using `data`? It's nice to have multiple answers showing different options.

Comment: I tried this in my class and it doesn't bind to click event, it just executes the method when the document loads.